# build AOSP with device owner configuration

Tags: android-source, device-owner

I want to build AOSP with a Device Manager app.

How can I build the AOSP with device_owner.xml and device_policies.xml already configured ?

PS: My target will be nexus5.

Answer (score 4):

I guess it is a  bit late for you, but for the others looking for the exact same thing (like I was), there is a great article about kiosk mode with lots of tech details:

http://trac.gateworks.com/wiki/Android/Kiosk

Details regarding the device ownership:

"However, if building from source you can bypass the request to the user and give your app device ownership/admin on first boot by injecting the following two files under out/target/product/ventana/data/system/. The injection is done by adding the files to the `PRODUCT_COPY_FILES` variable in your device configuration file (ie device/gateworks/ventana/ventana.mk)."

#### TL;DR:

just add this to the end of your device config file (.mk) using your configured ownership/policy xmls:

```
# Set device ownership for the kiosk mode app
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
    device/gateworks/ventana/device_owner.xml:data/system/device_owner.xml \
    device/gateworks/ventana/device_policies.xml:data/system/device_policies.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not enough, adding the files directly to /data/system will not survive a factory reset (wiping the data partition).

Instead you will need to add your `device_owner.xml` and `device_policies.xml` to your system partition (any folder, could be simply under `/system/`), then edit your init.rc file to copy `device_owner.xml` and `device_policies.xml`, this should be done in a `on post-fs-data` section (executed after the data partition has been mounted).

Dont' forget to set the correct permissions to said files `chmod 0600` and `chown system sytem`

your makefile should look like:

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
    device/gateworks/ventana/device_owner.xml:system/device_owner.xml \
    device/gateworks/ventana/device_policies.xml:system/device_policies.xml
```

your init.rc file should look like:

```
on post-fs-data
    # set device manager as device owner
    copy /system/device_owner_2.xml /data/system/device_owner_2.xml
    chmod 0600 /data/system/device_owner_2.xml
    chown system system /data/system/device_owner_2.xml
    copy /system/device_policies.xml /data/system/device_policies.xml
    chmod 0600 /data/system/device_policies.xml
    chown system system /data/system/device_policies.xml
```

Comment: I followed steps for android 13 but system doesn't boot, and goes to recovery mode. Any suggestion?

Comment: I want to add that this only works when adding to init.rc _after_ the line starting with `mkdir /data/system`.